# Doctrine GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") not working

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine with symfony2 and sqlite database and I have a problem inserting values as the id is not incremented anymore. I just changed a field annotation and I have drop the database and created it again with:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=dev
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

response:

```
Database schema updated successfully! "4" queries were executed
```

I have done the update a second time and I had

```
Database schema updated successfully! "14" queries were executed
```

I have a class "Post":

```
namespace Llafon\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") //I also tried "AUTO"
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $date;   

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User") //This variable was an integer before
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $image_name;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }
```

Now I have done this to insert:

```
    public function addAction(Request $request) {        
        $post = new Post();
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $post->setAuthor($user); //$user is not null
        $post->setContent("zz");
        $post->setImageName("aaa");
        $post->setTitle("fff");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();die();
}
```

I get this error the second time I execute this function:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO post (title, content, date, image_name, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["fff", "zz", "2015-10-25 21:45:37", "aaa", 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: post.id
```

So we can see here that the autoincrement didn't work(the id should be '2').

I also cleared the symfony cache but it didn't change anything.

However if I change the $author type to integer(instead of join), the autoincrement works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The problem lies with your column names. Since you did not set a name for `$id` Doctrine automatically converts the name of the property to a column name. And then when we look at your `$author` property we clearly see this - `JoinColumn(name="id")` which causes the problem. Change the name to `author_id` for instance and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Artamiel, the problem was with column names. "Since you did not set a name for $id Doctrine automatically converts the name of the property to a column name. And then when we look at your $author property we clearly see this - JoinColumn(name="id") which causes the problem. Change the name to author_id for instance and you will be good to go"